# Kendo Scheduler, update an event when opening to editing

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm using a Kendo Scheduler. The dataSource loaded and has data.

When I open an event to edit I want to get fresh data from the server for this event. The event may be modified by other users, and I will see old loaded data.

Is there ability to get data from server before opening an event to edit?

Answer (score 1):

When selecting the event you want to edit, you can refresh the scheduler's datasource. This should ensure you have the latest data. To prevent unneeded refreshes you can check if you're selecting an event, or an empty square.

Something like this:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    selectable: true,
    change: scheduler_change,
    views: [
        "day",
        { type: "week", selected: true },
        "month",
        "agenda",
        "timeline"
    ],
    etc...
});

function scheduler_change(e) {
    if (e.events.length > 0) {
        e.sender.dataSource.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thought. I thought about this, but this approach may take more time  on requesting data than getting data for one event only.
thanks again, will move in this direction...